# What is “floating proportions” in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, floating-point, kernel

In file `lib/proportions.c` of Linux kernel, floating proportions is implemented. Comments at the head of this file say

```
The floating proportion is a time derivative with an exponentially decaying
history:

 p_{j} = \Sum_{i=0} (dx_{j}/dt_{-i}) / 2^(1+i)
```

Please help to clarify the formula and give a simple example here.

Comment: [http://www.forkosh.com/mathtex.cgi?p_{j}%20=%20\sum_{i=0}%20%28dx_{j}/dt_{-i}%29%20/%202^%281+i%29](http://www.forkosh.com/mathtex.cgi?p_{j}%20=%20\sum_{i=0}%20%28dx_{j}/dt_{-i}%29%20/%202^%281+i%29)

Comment: i think you look here http://lwn.net/Articles/245603/